# How can I build a shortcut to an EXE file under Win10 (64bit)?

Tags: windows-10, total-commander

I want to get the full path to SnippingTool.exe in Win10 (I need it in Total Commander).
I looked in TaskManager and its says the path is: C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe  The program can be found in WindowsExplorer at that 'location'.

However, when I open that folder in Total Commander 8 I cannot find the program. Also take a look what happens if I enter this command at command prompt:

```
C:\>"C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe"
'"C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
C:\>
```

---

Update:
**More oddities:**

I made shortcut on Desktop from WinExplorer. If works. I made a copy of the shortcut and the copy doesn't work:

> "The item SnippingTool.exe that this shortcut refers to has been
>   changed or moved, so this shortcu will no longer work properly. Do you
>   want to delete this shortcut? [Yes] [No]"

Smells like 'virtualisation'. Right?

Comment: can you find it with windows explorer?

Comment: @MátéJuhász-please see update

Comment: Can you use Snipping Tool? It appears to not exist on your system...

Comment: Is your question "how to create a shortcut" or "how to fix the issue of not being able to run it using command prompt", or "not being able to find it in Total Commander"?

Comment: Try running the command prompt as administrator and try again. SnippingTool requires elevated privileges to be run throught the command prompt.

Comment: @Insane-We don't know which is the problem... yet. Anyway, 2 and 3 does not apply because other program are running from command prompt and Total Commander can find other files.

Comment: @Leathe-shouldn't Windows say "you don't have privileges to run this program..." or something like this?

Comment: @thelight Nope. Not when running from the command prompt. Some commands are simply disabled/inaccessible if you're not using elevated privileges. You should however be able to change the permission for SnippingTool.exe to give normal users the right to use it like that. (Right click SnippingTool.exe -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Edit.. and allow all for a specific user.)

Comment: Try to type the command without quotes and not copy paste (or check the keyboard). The shortcut thing is a bug in the windows shell since win 7.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using 32-bit TotalCommander on a 64-bit Windows.
I have no problem finding the SnippingTool with my TC (64-bit) on my 64-bit Windows 10.
32-bit software (including TC if you use the 32-bit version) gets no access to the real system32 folder. It will be re-directed to syswow64 instead.
This is not Windows 10 specific.  64-bit Windows is designed to work this way. It happens on 64-bti Vista, WIn7 and Win8 too.